# Can't convert Photoshop opacity to CSS3

Tags: css, transparency, opacity, photoshop

My PSD contains something like this:

[image]

As you can see this is a simple background with a text block (color: #ffffff). I've applied a 3% opacity on the text layer like this:

[image]

When I try to reproduce this in CSS, the text color is far more darker in the browser and I don't understand why:

[image]

Here is the CSS

```
.a-text {
  color:       rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03);
  font-size:   200px;
  font-family: "Lato Black";
}
```

This is not a color profile issue or something. As you can see the background color is exactly the same. And this is not a CSS rule conflict. There is something wrong with the transparency that I've maybe misunderstood.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: `0.03` is nearly invisible... why did you pick such low number?

Comment: looks fine to me anyway. this is a matter of taste and not a question for this website

Comment: The designer of this project working a lot with color opacity. He choose some base colors and apply many opacities. I find this good because i'm working with scss and I can use darken or lighten on the base colors. it's maybe a bad practice  I don't really know...

Comment: And yes 0.03 opacity is nearly invisible in CSS3. But with the 3% photoshop opacity it looks visible enough: http://i.imgur.com/Xgv082U.png (see the videos title)

Comment: I don't understand the last comment, what does photoshop has to do with the CSS?

Comment: I mean the opacity value you can set on a photoshop layer (see the screenshot). 
I thought you can "reproduce" exactly the same opacity in CSS3 with this photoshop value. 
Example: 50% in photoshop = opacity:0.5. 
But don't get the same result in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks correct and I don't think you've misunderstood anything. Its going to be hard to reproduce fonts and effects/styles placed on the fonts completely perfectly when moving from a graphics tool to code. What you have is a bit close you may just want to bump up the opacity a bit. If you need your graphics to be perfect regarding opacity shades etc I recommend using SVG.

Comment: Okey I got you, I thought the opacity value had a "universal" render regardless of the support (Photoshop or browser). I was wrong. I'll just move up the CSS opacity and it will be fine for me. 
Thank for your help.

Answer (score -1):

You might try the CSS opacity feature, which in theory should result in the same result as a rgba value — but who knows. I suspect that results vary from browser to OS. Can't test here. I would also opt bumping.

```
.a-text {
    color:       white;
    opacity:     .03;
    font-size:   200px;
    font-family: "Lato Black";
}
```

Comment: Already tried, and have exactly the same result. 
But yes this is maybe caused by my working env, I'm working on a linux based OS and play photoshop in a windows box with vine. I'm curious to know if someone have the same result on Windows or MacOSX.